# What System Image should I need to download?

Tags: android

My System Specifications,
Acer Aspire 5733Z
Physical Memory - 2GB
Intel HD Graphics
Windows 7 Pro 64 bit
500GB HDD
No Hyper-V is available

In the last week I downloaded Android Studio for Windows 7. I installed it successfully. But the Android Virtual Devices are not working. It says I do not have Intel HAXM. I downloaded it's setup. When trying to install it shows, this error,
[image: HAXM installation error]

And I have decided to download another System Image that is suitable for Windows 7 64-Bit. What should I select from the following packages? Plz answer!

[image: The packages]

Comment: I am using Android 5.11 Platform. What should I download?

Comment: ARM EABI one or the Intel x86 Atom_64 one?